# Fitted value iteration algorithm of Markov Reinforcement Learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, model-fitting

In Andrew Ng's fitted value iteration algorithm, which I gave the detail steps as below, it will try to find the best action of one state s(i) in step 3. when the agent was in s(i), we execute the possible action a(1) and we transited to s(i)'.

My question is how we can reverted to s(i) again and executed the 2nd possible action a(2)? Suppose, we use this algorithm to control a helicopter, I think we can not revert state back easily.

#### Algorithm

```
1. Randomly sample m states s(1), s(2), . . . s(m) ∈ S.
2. Initialize θ := 0.
3. Repeat {
    For i = 1, . . . , m {
        For each action a ∈ A {
            Sample s′ 1, . . . , s′ k ∼ Ps(i)a (using a model of the MDP).
            Set q(a) = k1 Pk j=1 R(s(i)) + γV (s′ j)
            // Hence, q(a) is an estimate of R(s(i))+γEs′∼P
            s(i)a[V (s′)].
        }
        Set y(i) = maxa q(a).
        // Hence, y(i) is an estimate of R(s(i))+γ maxa Es′∼P
        s(i)a[V (s′)].
   }
   // In the original value iteration algorithm (over discrete states)
   // we updated the value function according to V (s(i)) := y(i).
   // In this algorithm, we want V (s(i)) ≈ y(i), which we’ll achieve
   // using supervised learning (linear regression).
   Set θ := arg minθ 1 2 Pm i=1 θT φ(s(i)) − y(i)2
}
```

Comment: Hi @J0hnnyJiang, could you provide a reference (a paper or something similar) for the algorithm you are talking about?

Comment: @PabloEM here is the paper http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes12.pdf, mentioned algo is at section 4.2.2. Suppose we control a helicopter and its state changed randomly because of wind speed etc...In step 3 for each action loop, how can we revert to the same s(i) state and execute different actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the algorithm you are refering to, described in section 4.2.2, is part of the "parent" section *4.2. Value function approximation*. And the first section is *4.2.1 Using a model or simulation*.

In the first section, we can read:

> To develop a value function approximation algorithm, we will assume
>   that we have a **model**, or **simulator**, for the MDP. Informally, a simulator
>   is a black-box that takes as input any (continuous-valued) state `s_t` and
>   action `a_t`, and outputs a next-state `s_{t+1}` sampled according to the state
>   transition probabilities `P_{s_t, a_t}`

Therefore, the algorithm it is assuming that you can use de model/simulator to simulate that you apply all the possible actions to the same state. As you have notice, if you have a real environment (i.e., not a model nor simulator), like a helicopter, it is not possible to apply several actions to the same state, because after applying the action the state would change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that really help. So this algo can not work under a real environment.